# memory leak in AKPeriodicFunction

Tags: audiokit

I have been using AudioKit 4.7.1 AKPeriodicFunction on macOS and noticed memory growing even for simple use cases.  I have not tested on iOS yet.

I implemented a simple example that you can run through Leaks to track the memory.

```swift
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/leadloop.wav"
        let player = AKPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))!
        player.isLooping = true
        let periodicFunction = AKPeriodicFunction(frequency: 5.0){
        }
        AudioKit.output = player
        try? AudioKit.start(withPeriodicFunctions:periodicFunction)
        periodicFunction.start()
        player.play()
```

Memory should not be increasing in this example.  Here is the heaviest part of the stack trace that may be helpful,

```
  11 AudioToolbox   34.11 MB     __26-[AUAudioUnit renderBlock]_block_invoke
  10 macos-leak-test   34.11 MB     __52-[AKOperationGeneratorAudioUnit internalRenderBlock]_block_invoke
   9 macos-leak-test   34.11 MB     DSPKernel::processWithEvents(AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned int, AURenderEvent const*)
   8 macos-leak-test   34.11 MB     AKOperationGeneratorDSPKernel::process(unsigned int, unsigned int)
   7 macos-leak-test   34.11 MB     plumber_compute
   6 macos-leak-test   34.11 MB     plumbing_compute
   5 macos-leak-test   34.11 MB     sporth_fexec
   4 macos-leak-test   34.11 MB     akCustomUgenFunction(plumber_data*, sporth_stack*, void**)
   3 libobjc.A.dylib   34.11 MB     -[NSObject autorelease]
```

Comment: This is one of those rare cases where I actually prefer having a Github issue as opposed to a StackOverflow question. You have identified a leak with a simple example and we're definitely on the hook to take care of it. Thank you.

Comment: I was undecided myself.  I've added an [issue on github](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1870).